# storing HTML on mongoDB. what is the right approach and data type

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am new to mongoDB, and I am aiming to have a formatted text area on front-end using angular. The result of this is HTML.

How can i store it on mongo?

It cannot recognize the value because of a quote within the HTML.

My collection:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5536a1707883457072177e95"),
    "bc_title" : "TEST",
    "bc_post_time" : ISODate("2014-02-10T10:50:42.389Z"),
    "bc_body_html" : "",
    "bc_body_plain" : "T .....TEST TEST ",
    "bc_img_url" : "../img/url/test.png",
    "bc_category" : "news",
    "bc_created_by" : "mhhonline"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A standard String should be able to store HTML inside Mongodb.

Keep in mind that you should be very careful to sanitize html that goes into a database of any sort.

Comment: you are right. it seems the tool i am using has a sort of bug. i used www.robomongo.org tool. when i tried the command line, it worked fine. when i edit on the tool, it adds slash before the quotes  "<html lang = \"eng\"> <body ng-app=\"userApp\" ng-controller=\"mainController as main\"> test</body></html>"

Comment: @MohammedAl-Hanabi If this is correct, could you please mark it as so?

Comment: I have done this in a project where I have gotten to more than 25000 documents in which html is stored. Now the search has become difficult for me. because if someone tries to search "class" it matches all the documents having the word "class" which is a general term used in html. and almost all get matched up. So now i'm kind of regret this.